# How do I compare the 2 numbers I've inserted to check which one is greater in TASM dosbox?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

So I made a program that states if 2 numbers are similar:

```
dosseg
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
        msg1 db 10,13,"Insert first number ...$"
        msg2 db 10,13,"Insert second number ...$"
        msg3 db 10,13,"The numbers are similar ...$"
        msg4 db 10,13,"The numbers are not similar ...$"
                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                        

.code
main proc
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax       

        mov dx,offset msg1      
        mov ah,9
        int 21h


       mov ah,1         
       int 21h

       mov cl,al        

       mov dx,offset msg2       
       mov ah,9
       int 21h

       mov ah,1         
       int 21h

       mov dl,al        

       cmp dl,cl        

       je l1    

       mov dx,offset msg4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
       mov ah,9
       int 21h
                jmp exit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        l1:

        mov dx,offset msg3       
        mov ah,9
        int 21h

        exit:

     mov ah,4ch         
     int 21h
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                               
main endp

end main
```

I want to know how I can then compare these two numbers to check and print which one is greater. Thank you in advance.

I'm a total noob at this, sorry if I messed up something in the inline code box.

Comment: find out what other jumps (apart from `je`) exists and how do they work

Answer (score 0):

In `cmp dl,cl` you are not yet comparing the inputted numbers! What you are comparing are the ASCII codes for the keys that you have pressed on the keyboard. eg. If you press <kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd>, you would be comparing 56 and 51. You get the actual numbers by subtracting 48 before doing anything else.

```
mov  ah, 01h         
int  21h
sub  al, '0'     ; This subtracts 48
mov  cl, al

mov  ah, 01h         
int  21h
sub  al, '0'     ; This subtracts 48
mov  dl, al

cmp  cl, dl
j??  ???         ; One of the many conditional jumps
```

### If your numbers are **unsigned** values.

'Bigger than' gets named **above**
'Smaller than' gets named **below**

`ja` will jump if the value from CL is above the value from DL
`jae` will jump if the value from CL is above or equal to the value from DL
`jb` will jump if the value from CL is below the value from DL
`jbe` will jump if the value from CL is below or equal to the value from DL

### If your numbers are **signed** values.

'Bigger than' gets named **greater**
'Smaller than' gets named **less**

`jg` will jump if the value from CL is greater than the value from DL
`jge` will jump if the value from CL is greater than or equal to the value from DL
`jl` will jump if the value from CL is less than the value from DL
`jle` will jump if the value from CL is less than or equal to the value from DL

Comment: For single-digit integers, it's actually fine to compare their ASCII codes.  (And it's a single character with no room for a minus sign, so signed-positive and unsigned are equivalent)